# Chai Request With URL instead of JS File

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I know how to make chai requests of the form:

```
let Server = require('../src/index');
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chaiHttp');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

and then test using:

```
chai.request(Server).get('/').end((error,response) => {
  ....
});
```

However, how could I do this if I wanted `Server` to be a URL instead - for example I'd want to send a GET request to `https://myserver.com` and test what the response is with Chai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chai HTTP to use an URL instead of server by replacing `Server` parameter in the `request` method.

```
chai.request( "https://myserver.com" )
    .get( "/" )
    ...
```

Will make a *GET* request to `https://myserver.com`.

You can read more about this feature in the [Official Documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/)